# Controlling lighting in Edit Mode

Tags: edit-mode

How do I control (increase) lighting in Edit Mode? Some parts of my object are really dark, making it hard to edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control the lighting of the mesh via the user preferences. However if some of the faces are dark and others not, it is a telltale sign of a certain flaw in your mesh: normals pointing inwards. You can fix it by selecting all (<kbd>A</kbd>), hitting space and looking for Recalculate Normals.

If you want to read up on normals, see Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)

Comment: Was it normals facing inside?